# Laravel - condition on nested models

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm writing a code to get nested objects in Laravel. I was wondering if it is possible to write conditions in hasMany or belongsTo.

Here is what I'm doing, that makes the question clear:

```
$posts = Post::where(
            array(
                'status' => 'active'
            )
        )
        ->orderBy('id', 'asc')
        ->with(['postResponsibilities' => function($query){
            $query->where('status', 'active');
        }])
        ->with(['postRequirements' => function($query){
            $query->where('status', 'active');
        }])
        ->with(['postSalaries' => function($query){
            $query->where('status', 'active');
        }])
        ->skip($limit * ($page - 1))->take($limit)->get();
```

So, I have to put nested queries to get only those records whose **status** is **active**.

In the Post model, I've written:

```
public function postRequirements(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\PostRequirement', 'post_id');
}

public function postResponsibilities(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\PostResponsibility', 'post_id');
}

public function postSalaries(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\PostSalary', 'post_id');
}
```

Is there a way such that I can define status condition inside the nested models?
So that I can write:

```
$posts = Post::where(
            array(
                'status' => 'active'
            )
        )
        ->orderBy('id', 'asc')
        ->with('postResponsibilities')
        ->with('postRequirements')
        ->with('postSalaries')
        ->skip($limit * ($page - 1))->take($limit)->get();
```

I hope the question is clear, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is apply those conditions inside the relationship methods you put on the Post model, for example:

`class Post
{
    public function postRequirements() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\PostRequirement', 'post_id')
            ->where('status', 'active');
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to eager load multiple relationships.

See: https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

In your case it would be something like:

```
Post::with('postResponsibilities', 'postRequirements', 'postSalaries')->where()....
```